# Why does my code enter the second else if even when it is false?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub txt_Number_of_sites_Change()
    If IsNumeric(txt_Number_of_sites.Value) And txt_Number_of_sites.Value <= 20 And txt_Number_of_sites > 0 Then
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim j As Integer
        Dim x As Integer
        Dim AWS
        Dim diff 'diffrence between AWS and number of sites
        AWS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count - 1
        If AWS = 1 Then
            If txt_Number_of_sites.Value = 1 Then
                IT_Staff.Visible = xlSheetVisible
                ElseIf txt_Number_of_sites.Value > 1 Then
                IT_Staff.Visible = xlSheetVisible
                For i = 2 To txt_Number_of_sites.Value
                Sheets("IT Staff").Select
                Sheets("IT Staff").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
                Next
            End If
        ElseIf AWS < txt_Number_of_sites.Value Then
            diff = txt_Number_of_sites - AWS
            For i = 1 To diff
            Sheets("IT Staff").Select
            Sheets("IT Staff").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
            Next
        ElseIf AWS > txt_Number_of_sites.Value Then
            x = 0
            j = Sheets.Count
            For x = j To 19 Step -1 '# <- please note the change here
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Sheets(x).Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            Next x
        End If
        ElseIf txt_Number_of_sites.Value = "" Then
        Exit Sub
        Else
        msgbox "Please enter a numberic value from 1-20"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What 'Else' is it entering? Where is the problem?

Comment: it is entering this one `ElseIf AWS < txt_Number_of_sites.Value Then`

Comment: Then `AWS` is not equal to `1` AND `AWS` is less than `txt_Number_of_sites.Value`. That's the only way that could happen. Perhaps stick a breakpoint on that `ELSEIF` line and check the value of `txt_number_of_sites.value` to see what it is.

Comment: @JNevill i tested that and it didn't work i dont know what to do now

Comment: What is your value for `AWS` and `txt_number_sites.value` when you break on that line?

Comment: the value for `AWS` is 3 and the value of `txt_Number_of_sites.Value` is 2

Comment: Try my modified code below and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out the modified code below. I fixed quite a few areas where you were bound to encounter an issue. A bit of advice, never ever leave an unqualified reference (i.e "Sheets("Sheetname" where we never point to the workbook).

Also, I found a spot where you had a premature "End If" that I couldn't trace back to an independent If statement. This likely was causing part of your issue.

```
Private Sub txt_Number_of_sites_Change()
    ' You use this number repeatedly, just declare a variable.
    Dim SiteCount As Long
    If IsNumeric(txt_Number_of_sites.Value) Then
        SiteCount = txt_Number_of_sites.Value
    Else
        ' Handle this here. What should happen if text is entered instead?
        ' For now, we will just exit the routine.
        Exit Sub
    End If

' Once SiteCount is declared as long, we no longer need to check for IsNumeric.
If SiteCount <= 20 And SiteCount > 0 Then
    ' Use long instead of Integer. Or use double if you need non-round numbers.
    Dim AWS As Long

    ' Qualify this Workbook reference. Absolutely avoid ActiveWorkbook unless absolutely neccesary.
    AWS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count - 1

    ' Consider using ThisWorkbook if you are running this code in the same workbook being targeted.
    ' AWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count - 1

    Dim i As Long
    Dim diff As Long  'diffrence between AWS and number of sites
    If AWS = 1 Then
        If SiteCount = 1 Then
            ' Is this a CodeName?
            IT_Staff.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        ElseIf txt_Number_of_sites.Value > 1 Then
            IT_Staff.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        End If

        For i = 2 To SiteCount
            ' Qualify these sheet references. Or use the codename.
            ' There's no need to select the sheet before copying.
            'Sheets("IT Staff").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("IT Staff").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
            ' Or
            ' IT_Staff.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        Next
    ElseIf AWS < SiteCount Then
        diff = SiteCount - AWS
        For i = 1 To diff
            ' See my above note about qualification
            'Sheets("IT Staff").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("IT Staff").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        Next
    ElseIf AWS > SiteCount Then
        Dim x As Long
        x = 0
        ' Qualify this reference as well.
        'j = Sheets.Count
        j = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count

        ' Why would you declare a j variable just to not use it? Just set x = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count instead.
        ' No need to repeatedly toggle Application.DisplayAlerts
        ' Also, you shouldnt hardcode the 19 here. Set it equal to Sheets.Count - 1 or something similar. Otherwise you will
        ' inevitably run into a Subscript Out of Range error.
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        For x = j To 19 Step -1 '# <- please note the change here
            Sheets(x).Delete
        Next
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        ' It looks like you have a premature End If here causing an issue.
        ' End If <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

        ' This is impossible since we are using a number for the condition in the first place.
        ' ElseIf txt_Number_of_sites.Value = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
Else
    MsgBox "Please enter a numeric value from 1-20"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the help but im getting a block if without if error now

Comment: Try again. That should fix it.